# Is $U = \left\{A \in \mathbb{M}^ {n \times n}(\mathbb{R} ): \ker{A} \cap \text{Im}A = \{\vec{0}\} \right\}$ a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I recently tried to prove or reject the conjecture that the set of matrices

$$U = \left\{A \in \mathbb{M}^ {n \times n}(\mathbb{R} ): \ker{A} \cap \text{Im}A = \{\vec{0}\} \right\}$$

is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{M}^{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$.

---

I didn't find it hard to prove that the set is multiplicative: Assume that $A \in U$. We know that $\ker{0}\cap \text{Im}0 = \vec{0}$. So in the case that $\lambda=0$ we are done. Suppose that $\lambda \neq 0$. It follows easily that $\ker{A}=\ker{\lambda A}$ and that $\text{Im}A = \text{Im}{\lambda A}$.

I thought additivity was the hardest part. I don't have a good intition when it comes to " adding" linear maps. Can you help me with this?

Comment: What is your gut feeling, will it be a subspace or not?

Comment: I really don't know. I'm sorry

Comment: Ah, so you don't know whether to look for a proof or a counterexample. That makes it harder, of course. For $n = 1$, we have $U = \mathbb{M}^{1\times 1}(\mathbb{R})$, so that is a linear subspace. Look at $n = 2$. How does an $A$ with $\ker A \cap \operatorname{im} A \neq \{0\}$ look like?

Comment: Uuuhhm... well by the dimension theorem, we know that kernel and image must be a line. They must be the same line. Se if we'd apply him twice, we would become the zero matrix. Is that right?

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin : If you're unsure, I recommend trying to prove $U$ _is_ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ by attempting to prove it satisfies the three requirements of the usual test.  If it works, then you're done.  If it doesn't seem to work, then show convincingly that one of the requirements fails.

Comment: @KoenraadvanDuin Right. You have $A \neq 0$ and $A^2 = 0$. Write down such a matrix and see whether you can write it as the sum of two matrices from $U$. If you can, you have the answer, if you cannot, you will understand why.

Comment: I think I've got it, but it's hard to latex it without seeing my own output. I hope you understand me when I write: $(0 1; 1 0) + (0 1; -1 0) =(0 2; 0 0)$. Well the first " matrices"  are invertible, so they belong to $U$, but the righthand matrix does not because its kernel is its image is a line.

Comment: Right. Well done. It should be clear that that result extends to all higher dimensions. Make it an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ be a simple matrix $\notin U$ for dimension $2$, say $\ker A={\rm im\,} A=\langle e_1\rangle$ where $e_1=\pmatrix{1\\0}$, e.g. take
$$A:=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}$$
with this example, $A+I$ and $I$ both have trivial kernel, so $A+I$ and $I$ are in $U$ but $A\notin U$, so $U$ is not closed under addition.

Comment: Rather: not closed under subtraction... Unless you mention $-I$ is in $U$, for instance :-)

Comment: OP already proved that $U$ is closed under all scalar multiplications, including $(-1)\cdot$. But anyway, you are right, I was also hesitating to state it like that...